# IndexError: tuple index out of range by max pooling

Tags: keras, max-pooling

I am using keras functional api and I have tensor of shape

```
phrasing.shape = (?, 553777, 19, 3)
```

Now I want to take a max feature of `unigram` and `bigram` & `trigram`
so the expected shape should be

```
(?, 553777, 19, 1)
```

so I added this line

```
ph = MaxPooling2D ( pool_size=(1,3)  )(phrasing)
```

and get this error :
IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: What is "this error"?

Comment: IndexError: tuple index out of range

Comment: Please add all relevant infomation to the question - an error message is not something that should be searched in the comment section

Comment: I have edited it

Answer (score 0):

Your data is a dimension too high. I had the same issue and I solved it by dropping the layers from Conv2d to Conv1d and MaxPooling2d to MaxPooling1d. Which makes sense depending on your data format which in my case was text classification.